# Different pixel value extraction using IplImage (C++) and BufferedImage (JAVA)

Tags: image-processing, bufferedimage, iplimage

I'm currently converting a code that I've done in JAVA into C++ that uses some machine learning algorithm.
The problem is that some pixel values are different if I load the image under java with respect to loading them in C++ (OpenCV).
The JAVA code is:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new java.io.FileInputStream("lena.jpg"));
```

The C++ code is:

```
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );
```

When I try to compare the pixel values I obtain differences like:

IplImage

```
169 72 83 
174 70 79 
183 72 81 
188 74 82
```

BufferedImage

```
170 63 73
175 65 74
183 72 79
188 74 82
```

As you can see the values are similar, but not the same and this causes some problems in the machine learning algorithm. Did someone had the same issues?

Answer (score 0):

The Jpeg decoder library implementation might be different. Not a big issue.

Comment: Sorry. The problem is in my code.
cvGet2d(img,x,y) return a different pixel. The solution is simply use cvGet2d(img,y,x) (x for wigth, y for height) in for cicle.